# Microcontroller Constant Power Output - Is this Okay?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, power, current, dac

I have found one circuit on this site and I want to use it for my project.

My project is power controlled heater coil. I use low resistance coils in range of 0.6Ω - 2Ω so they must be precisely controlled. How I want to achieve this?

1. I will use Arduino and first of all I will measure current Voltage on the battery (V BAT).
2. Desired power will be set in the Arduino code. For example 30W.
3. Now, If I want 30W power output with 4.2V for example I will need about I = 7.14 Amp to flow through heater. This is calculated by Ohm's Law.
4. Through DAC I will calculate controller output voltage (U REF) with this formula **UREF = I * RREF**. So it will be 7.14*0.15 = 1.071V.

[image]

Is this circuit okay?

**EDIT**

Power must be strictly controlled. The coil will work only few second 6-8 times per hour, so efficiency is not important.

Comment: By using a linear current source approach you are shifting heat between your  heating coil and your FET.  You would be better off using PWM to turn FET fully on and off to get your average power delivered to the heater. It would be much more efficient considering you are running from a battery.

Comment: I know that, but power must be strictly controlled. The coil will work only few second 6-8 times per hour, so efficiency is not important.

Comment: "Strictly controlled" means nothing in the engineering world.  What are your target specs?  What makes you think that you can't strictly control the power with PWM?  Also, check the common mode input voltage range on your op-amp.   And the minimum recommended supply voltage for the TL081 is 5V.  If your boost converter tolerance puts the output at 4.5V or 4.75V you are in trouble with supply and common mode input voltage.

Comment: For example I want 30W constant power output to heater. Heater is low impedance and it will work only 4-6 secs few times per hour. So per hour it will work about 40-60 seconds.

Comment: If you really need 30W you can't get even close if your heater is >>0.6 ohms or if your battery is << 4.2V.  If 30W is just an example on the high side you may be OK.  You have to look at the worst case power dissipation in the FET and heatsink it appropriately.  Also, I don't see any decoupling caps on your amplifier.

Comment: @MiljanIlić: If you tell us what you are really trying to accomplish - what the heater is doing - we may be able to give better help. There are a few questions asked in the comments that you haven't answered.

Comment: @Transistor It is vaping device.

Answer (score 0):

The battery voltage will change once you start drawing current and will change during the 4-6 seconds. The resistance of your (vaping heater?) will also change significantly as it heats.

The MOSFET you show is unsuitable, you will need one that can turn on fully with the output voltage the op-amp can supply, given a 5V supply voltage. T Similarly, the op-amp needs to be  a type that can accept the required common mode range at the inputs, and produce enough voltage at the minimum supply voltage to fully turn the MOSFET on. The default type you show is unsuitable.

You cannot get 30W with only 4.2V and 0.6 ohms, let alone 2 ohms. Even if the MOSFET is 0.005 ohms the sense resistor is 0.15 ohms, so the maximum power is 23.4W.

You might do better to thermally model the heater and simply power it on fully until the integral wrt time of voltage*current reaches a setpoint (or use a slightly more sophisticated model and take losses into account).

Comment: How I can control power via PWM? How to calculate power that flows through heater?

Comment: The power is volts * A. The average power is the duty cycle times the power.

Comment: I don't know how much Amps flows through coil.

Comment: This is a problem. I want to limit power. Heater power is P = V^2 / R and it is maximum power that heater can deliver. Now I want to limit that power to lower than maximum.

Comment: You can measure the current. There are single chip current sensors that have very low drop and MCU-compatible outputs. Take a look around.